# Android: Get a file from http and store in SDCard

Tags: java, android, jsp

I've followed what is written in many similar questions but there is still a problem

From a jsp I get a pdf, if i go to the URL the browser opens automatically the pdf, jsp page does something like:

```
//Gets the pdf from the database
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(file.getBinaryStream(), buffer);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int readed=0;
while ((readed=bis.read())!=-1) baos.write(readed);
bis.close();
byte[] pdf=baos.toByteArray();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setContentLength(pdf.length);              
response.getOutputStream().write(pdf, 0, pdf.length);
```

This code works because if we browse to the URL we get the PDF into the browser.

Then in Android I do in an AsyncTask:

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
URL url = new URL(myurl); // <-- this is the same URL tested into browser
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.connect();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(getWorkingDir()+fileName);
InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength(); //<- this seems to be incorrect,     totalSize value is 22 but file is more than 50Kb length
int downloadedSize = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer
while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) >=0) {
  fos.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
  downloadedSize += bufferLength;
  // at this point downloadedSize is only 2, and next iteration in while exists so a file os size 2bytes is created...
}
fos.close();
```

Of course I've the permission to write in SD and use Internet in the AndrodiManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I've tried directly with URLConnection, getting the InputStream and we get the same, only reading 2 bytes...

Write to external file is working, if I try to write a `string.getBytes()` to a file it's written.

If we get `conn.getResponseCode()` it's 200, so it's ok.

The same .jsp can according to parameters return a list of documents (in JSON) or a PDF if we provide his database ID, if we get the list of pdf, it works, in this case it's readed like:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(line); 
}
```

Any idea why is not working when it tries to get the binary pdf file?

Where is the failure?

Thanks for your expertice...

Answer (score 2):

Its working for me Try to modify this :

```
private void savePrivateExternalFile(String fileURL, String fName) {
   HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    URL url = null;
    try {

        url = new URL(fileURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.addRequestProperty(BConstant.WEB_SERVICES_COOKIES,
                cookie);
             connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.connect();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    File folderDir = null;
        folderDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir("Directory Name") + "/Files");

    File file = new File(folderDir, fName);

    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }

    if ((folderDir.mkdirs() || folderDir.isDirectory())) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = null;

                bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream,
                        1024 * 5);

            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    folderDir + "/" + fName);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                while ((len1 = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                }

                bufferedInputStream.close();

            fileOutputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
            connection.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
```

Use this if you want to open Downloaded file :

```
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir("Directory Name")+ "/Files/" + fileName);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

#### Add this line in your Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Yes, tested and SAME problem, if I put a log inside the while, writting len1, it's only 2 (bytes) and there is no more iteration at while (next tiem len1==-1). Everything I've tried is supposed to work, but there is something I've missed some place, strange...  (only change I've to comment line connection.addRequestProperty(BConstant.WEB_SERVICES_COOKIES, cookie))

Comment: use my code u just need to change the url and fname. fname can be any String Name of the file. It will work like butter. Just try to HardCode the url and then run the code.

Comment: Your code worked in a java app, but not in the app, tried with harcoded string too and get same error, but found the problem, the code was ok (yours and I suppose my previous too),so problem is in the communication, as the url was redirected from external to internal server, seems there is some problem there or in the server, will check, code is working, thanks.

Comment: Argh I can not vote good to your answer because I have no reputation, but thanks!!!